Proof that the Weierstrass $\wp$-function is of order $2$
Let $L$ be a lattice generated by $\omega_1, \omega_2$, then I should prove that the elliptic Weierstrass $\wp-$function
$$\wp(z):=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{l \in L \setminus \{ 0 \}}{ \left(\dfrac{1}{(z-l)^2}-\dfrac{1}{l^2}\right) }$$
is a function of order $2$, i.e. for any fixed $u$, the function $\wp(z)-u$ has exactly two zeros (or a single double zero).
I'm not sure how to approach this problem. It might be useful to note that the function is even and that the zeros of the derivative { $\frac{\omega_1}{2}, \frac{\omega_2}{2},\frac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{2}$ } are quickly deductible from the fact that it is odd

For all $u \in \hat {\Bbb C}$ – including $u = \infty$ – is the order of an elliptic function $f$ equal to the number of solutions of $f(z) = u$ in the fundamental parallelogram, counted with multiplicity.
The Weierstrass elliptic function has poles exactly at the lattice points and all poles have multiplicity two. That makes one double pole in the fundamental parallelogram, i.e. the order is $2$.

Thank you, sorry for my late feedback.
All clear to me except the last sentence. In our definition of fundamental parallelogram, the opposite edges are included: $\Pi:={a \omega_1+b\omega_2 | 0 \leq a \leq 1, 0 \leq b \leq 1 }$ . Hence from what I see we have $3$ poles in $\Pi$: $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_1+\omega_2$. Also I don't see why one pole of multiplicity 2 in the fundamental parallelogram implies that the order of the function is $2$ (I may just not remember one key theorem from complex analysis here)

@TheLionKing: That is an unusual definition of the fundamental parallelogram. The usual definition is $\Pi ={a \omega_1+b\omega_2 | 0 \leq a < 1, 0 \leq b < 1 }$. With that definition, the number of roots of $f(z) - u$ in $\Pi$ is equal to the number of poles of $f$ in $\Pi$, both counted with multiplicity.
